# Redis Lock key in java

Tags: java, multithreading, server, redis

I am using **Redis** in my java project where i need to get the value of a key then do some modification and then again set the value of that key.
My requirement is that if one thread got the value of a key then another thread should wait until the first thread set the value for that key.
I could have used synchronised but we are using **multiple server** in our project so synchronised won't work for this condition.
Can anyone suggest me some other solution for this condition.

Comment: In the time it took you to type this question, you would be halfway through Redis' own [guide on distributed locks](https://redis.io/topics/distlock). Please do some research before posting a question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [Redisson](https://redisson.org) project is the perfect solution for you.

**Disclaimer: I am a member of Redisson project**

Redisson understands the need to have a more abstract way to work with redis, so we have created many objects and services that work on top of your own redis and exposes standard java interfaces. All those objects and services are distributed and thread safe.

To solve your problem, we have plenty [locks and synchronisers](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/8.-Distributed-locks-and-synchronizers) for you to choose from: Lock(ReentrantLock), FairLock, MultiLock, RedLock(as describe in the [official document](https://redis.io/topics/distlock), and yes we have read it all), ReadWriteLock, Semaphore, PermitExpirableSemaphore, CountDownLatch.

The usage can't be more simple:

Node1:

```
Config config = ;//create your own configuration object based on connections types
RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);

//The Lock is just a java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock
Lock lock = redisson.getLock("myLock");
lock.lock();

//or if you want to have a lease time on the lock
((RLock) lock).lock(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//do other business here.
lock.unlock();
```

Node2:

```
//The same as node1
```

If you would like to know a bit more please head to our website at https://redisson.org

Comment: I used Redisson in my project and it worked fine for some time but then it started giving me error as shown below. I don't know what is causing this error. [link] (https://codeshare.io/2EMNjN)

Comment: One of the possible cause is that you are trying to create lots of Redisson instances. Typically you only need to have one Redisson instance per application.

Comment: Can i create multiple **RLock** instance for one **RedissonClient** instance.

Comment: @Redisson_RuiGu do you have a guide for how to decide which lock to use? For example, if I have a Redis cluster, is FairLock safe to use?  Or does it have some issues that would suggest I setup additional independent Redis servers and use RedLock?